# ACS712 Current Sensor Data Plot using MATLAB and Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am working on a GUI to plot ac712 current data to MATLAB GUI. The problem is I cannot plot the data properly. The plot seems to be triangular and not sinusoidal curve. Also the current values are correct but I think x-axis values are incorrect. Please help.

```
clear all
clc
a = arduino('com3','uno');
samples = 200
for i = 1:201
    x = [0:0.001:2];
    y = zeros(1,201); 
    b = a.readVoltage(0);
    y(i) = ((b-2.5)/.234);
    i = i+1
    pause (0.006)
end
figure(1)
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Plot obtained using MATLAB]

<sup>*Fig. Plot obtained using MATLAB*</sup>

When I use arduino only for the same, the values for current are as follows:

```
0.46
-0.69
1.04
-0.94
0.81
-0.29
-0.06
0.71
-0.83
1.08
-0.81
0.62
0.04
-0.31
0.87
-0.87
1.1
-0.67
0.37
0.27
-0.56
1.02
-0.92
0.94
-0.46
0.08
0.52
-0.71
1.04
```

which when plotted using Excel is as follows:

[image: plot obtained with Arduino current data and x axis values as: 1-29]

<sup>*Fig. Plot obtained with Arduino current data and x axis values as: 1-29*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Are the time scales of both graphs the same?

What is the frequency of the signal you are trying to read?

Because the ACS712 uses chopper stabilization, the output signal is similar to your plot.

You may need to add or change the capacitor between the filter input pin and ground as shown on the typical application figure on the front page of the [ACS712 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf).

[image: Typical Application]

Comment: Update: I obatain the sinusoidal wave using arduino and MATLAB.

Comment: i got the answer. i am sampling current at 50Hz frequency, the problem is in the getting more samples using arduino and in a very timely manner. supposei take 40 smaples in one cycle. say first sample is taken at x time then the next 41st sample should be taken at (x+0.02). where 0.02 is the time period of one complete cycle. similarly every other samples

Comment: @ParamMehta Do you have an oscilloscope to look at the actual signal?

Comment: yes, we used Digital one and obtained perfect sinusoidal curve on it

Comment: What was your timebase? What does it look like with the timebase at 50nSec?